# Resubmitting Error in PHP Conatct form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

Apologies for my bad English. In my PHP contact form while I fill out the contents and submit, the `echo message` is showing.

While I try to refresh `“Confirm Form Resubmission”` is showing along with the message `"The mail has been sent successfully"`.

I need code for when I submitted the contact form after refresh the page won't display the `echo message` along with the confirm for re-submission message.

I am just starting out with PHP and I am not familiar with it. Can anybody help me please.

**PHP script**

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['randcheck']==$_SESSION['rand'])
{

$your_name = $_REQUEST['your_name'];

$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

$mobile_number = $_REQUEST['mobile_number'];

$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

$formcontent="From: $your_name \n Email: $email \n Phone Number: $mobile_number \n Message: $message";

$to = "mail@hotmail.com";

$subject = "Contact Form";

$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";


    if (($your_name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
        {
        $msg = "All fields are required";
        }
    else{       

       mail($to,$subject,$formcontent,$mailheader);

        $msg = "The mail has been sent successfully";
        }
    } 


?>
```

**HTML script**

```
<?php
   $rand=rand();
   $_SESSION['rand']=$rand;
?>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rand; ?>" name="randcheck" />

<form name="contactform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <label for="your_name">Your Name <font color="red">*</font></label>
      <input  type="text" name="your_name"  placeholder="Enter Your Name" maxlength="20" size="40" value="">

      <label for="email">Email Address <font color="red">*</font></label>
      <input  type="email" name="email" placeholder=" Enter Your E-mail Address" maxlength="20" size="40" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required value="">

      <label for="mobile_number">Mobile Number</label>
      <input  type="tel" name="mobile_number" pattern="[0-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number by Adding Country Code (eg: +91.,)" maxlength="30" size="40" value="">

      <label for="message">Message <font color="red">*</font></label>
      <textarea  name="message" placeholder="Your Message Goes Here" maxlength="1000" cols="62" rows="10" required></textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

      <div class="mail"> <?php echo $msg; ?> </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Why javascript and jquery tag?

Comment: You have to redirect your url to same page code is  header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

Comment: @saravana i think javascript and jquery will help for this issue

Comment: @Aravind no need of JS, jQuery. But be clear with your problem. I'm not able to understand the problem.

Comment: just try my solutions below

Comment: Better use captcha to prevent this kind of issues

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect after submitting, if someone refresh the page they go to redirect:

```
header('Location:  / new.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
Here you go (PHP File):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['randcheck']==$_SESSION['rand'])
    {
    $your_name = $_REQUEST['your_name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $mobile_number = $_REQUEST['mobile_number'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $your_name \n Email: $email \n Phone Number: 
    $mobile_number \n Message: $message";
    $to = "mail@hotmail.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
        if (($your_name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
            {
                $msg = "All fields are required";
            }
        else{       
                mail($to,$subject,$formcontent,$mailheader);
                $msg = "The mail has been sent successfully";
            }
    } 

unset($_POST['submit']);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<?php
   $rand=rand();
   $_SESSION['rand']=$rand;
?>
<form name="contactform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rand; ?>" name="randcheck" />

      <label for="your_name">Your Name <font color="red">*</font></label>
      <input  type="text" name="your_name"  placeholder="Enter Your Name" maxlength="20" size="40" value="">

      <label for="email">Email Address <font color="red">*</font></label>
      <input  type="email" name="email" placeholder=" Enter Your E-mail Address" maxlength="20" size="40" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required value="">

      <label for="mobile_number">Mobile Number</label>
      <input  type="tel" name="mobile_number" pattern="[0-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number by Adding Country Code (eg: +91.,)" maxlength="30" size="40" value="">

      <label for="message">Message <font color="red">*</font></label>
      <textarea  name="message" placeholder="Your Message Goes Here" maxlength="1000" cols="62" rows="10" required></textarea>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

      <div class="mail"> <?php echo $msg; unset($msg);?> </div>
</form>
```

**____________________________________________________________________________**

Add this at the bottom of PHP code, after the if..else block

```
unset($_POST['submit']);
```

And after `echo $msg`, add this

```
unset($msg);
```

The problem is that when you click on the submit button, variable gets stored and whenever the page is refreshed the initial check `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` returns true, so you get the $msg.

So, simply unset the values after using them.

**EDIT:**

Here's the solution for Redirect problem.
Add this at the start of your `<form>`

```
<?php
   $rand=rand();
   $_SESSION['rand']=$rand;
?>
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rand; ?>" name="randcheck" />
```

And then change your

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

to:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['randcheck']==$_SESSION['rand'])
```

Comment: but when refresh page it still ask every time to re submit page. what about that error ?

Comment: That's not an error. That's a feature of the Web Browser. You can't get rid of it. There's only one solution to that problem, which is to use AJAX

Comment: but you need to read the question properly they do not need that alert also. there is not only one solution. just redirect page and that alert was gone.

Comment: @MahipalPatel  the solution to resubmission is that instead of pressing F5 to refresh the page, simply click in the URL box and press enter.

Comment: But that's not a good solution, you're creating an extra redirect, which means an extra request for server to handle.

Comment: @MuhammadAsif unset function bro

Comment: @MahipalPatel check the Edit

Comment: this solutions also not work bro as they not use session_start() in current code

Comment: Now that's on him, to use `session_start()`. I'm here to give a solution, not a tutorial :)

Comment: @MuhammadAsif when i used session_start() the page is not loading bro it shows "This page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: Did you put a semi-colon after `session_start()` like this `session_start();` ?

Comment: @MuhammadAsif sry bro i forget to put it after i used the function session_start(); there is no change on my error. My php version in server is 5.6 will your code wrk on that version

Comment: @MuhammadAsif bro i just tried that what u say again the resubmission message and echo message is diaplaying after refreshing the page

Comment: @Aravind message will display but script will not run again

Comment: @MuhammadAsif but bro the code running when i submit the form i got 1 mail when i refresh the form again i got the main ever time if i refresh the page i got mail frequently

Comment: @MuhammadAsif kindly check it above updated code bro

Comment: @MuhammadAsif Mail not receiving and echo msg not displaying bro.,,

Answer (score -1):

USE SESSION VARIABLE TRY SOMETHING LIKE THIS.

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$your_name = $_REQUEST['your_name'];

$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

$mobile_number = $_REQUEST['mobile_number'];

$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

$formcontent="From: $your_name \n Email: $email \n Phone Number: 
$mobile_number \n Message: $message";

$to = "myname@hotmail.com";

$subject = "Contact Form";

$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";


if (($your_name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
    {
    $_SESSION['$msg'] = "All fields are required";
    }
else{       

   mail($to,$subject,$formcontent,$mailheader);

    $_SESSION['$msg'] = "The mail has been sent successfully";
    }
}
else
{ 
   unset($_SESSION['$msg']);

}
```

HTML part

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label for="your_name">Your Name <font color="red">*</font></label>
  <input  type="text" name="your_name"  placeholder="Enter Your Name" maxlength="20" size="40" value="">

  <label for="email">Email Address <font color="red">*</font></label>
  <input  type="email" name="email" placeholder=" Enter Your E-mail Address" maxlength="20" size="40" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required value="">

  <label for="mobile_number">Mobile Number</label>
  <input  type="tel" name="mobile_number" pattern="[0-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number by Adding Country Code (eg: +91.,)" maxlength="30" size="40" value="">

  <label for="message">Message <font color="red">*</font></label>
  <textarea  name="message" placeholder="Your Message Goes Here" maxlength="1000" cols="62" rows="10" required></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

  <div class="mail"> <?php if(isset($_SESSION['$msg'])){echo $_SESSION['$msg'] }; ?> </div>
    </form>
```